# Server and database query

Tags: database, server, hardware

Im trying to build a niche social network. I was just wondering what kind of hardware will i need (For database connection) and the costs of setting that up

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

I think it all depends on how many users u are expecting to host. And if you are willing to pay licenses for all the items required from software to hardware.